Automatic Switchover Between Two Supplies
I am using two power sources for my PCB (USB 5 V, power supply terminal 12-24 V). I want to power the board via USB if the power supply is not connected.
while I was looking for a solution, I came across this application from analog devices using LTC1473. I want to make sure if this application would be suitable or not.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from you to identify potential issues or improvements.

Please check the tags, this question is not related to kikad or stm32.

It'll probably work, but a simpler solution can be found here: Automatic Power Selection with MOSFET

Analog Devices did make it sure by providing results of their application research and development, if you read their conditions carefully. Unless you tried to breadboard the design :-(

Basic USB output power is only 5V, but the proposed other supply is 12V or 24V, so just make sure downstream circuits can accept this wide supply voltage range.  You'd have to give more details of application and current levels to fully examine, but a simple "diode OR" connection using rectifier diodes or Schottky diodes with appropriate current ratings is probably easiest, as long as the application can accept the power losses at the diodes.  Otherwise a voltage comparing pair of MOSFET switches such as @DaveTweed suggested are most efficient.
